# Node js concurrent DB I/O operations in mongoDB makes node memory frozen or fully occupied for certain process

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, design-patterns, cryptocurrency

NodeJS concurrent DB I/O operations in mongoDB makes memory frozen or fully occupied for one process. I'm not able read the DB queries when more concurrent write/read happens in the mentioned architecture which i've attached here in drive link. The memory frozen happens on any of the 3 services when the high load occurs.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Wkdv_gRzeW7LKrd-CdvTAyzjMLxtP5s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say the reason of locking just by seeing an image. However, it looks like your query locks table until query will be finished. If yes, then try to use `async` and `await`.

So this is a code example from [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/#await):

```
async function run() {
  ...
  try {
    res = await collection.updateOne(
      { name: "Mount McKinley" },
      { $set: { meters: 6190 } },
    );
    console.log(`Updated ${res.result.n} documents`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
  }
}
```